# Delay Java Step Execution

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to know if there is an easier way to dealy java execution.

```
function(){
  command 1;   
  thread.sleep();
  command 2;
  thread.sleep();
  ... and soo on
}
```

i want to delay each step in my function is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: How much easier could it possibly get?

Comment: I think this is the most clean way to do it. Why are you not satisfied with this option ?

Comment: are you using this in Java EE container as noted with the tags?

Comment: @Dave and Saury i know its the easiest way but say when i have 1000 step and i need delay after each step. so i am just looking for a work round for this i have no problem using the ancient ways ;) . Kris yes i am .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this, but I it is not good idea.
I agree with **DaveHowes**, that there is no another easy way to do that.

```
package main;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TempClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
        new TempClass().function();
    }

    private void function() throws NoSuchMethodException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final Class aClass = this.getClass();
        List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>() {{
            add(aClass.getDeclaredMethod("command1"));
            add(aClass.getDeclaredMethod("command2"));
        }};
        for (Method method : methods) {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(this);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void command1() {
        System.out.println("command1");
    }

    private void command2() {
        System.out.println("command2");
    }
}
```

Comment: woo i really love this thing wanna but i also wanna know performance wise is it better to do it this way or to opt the old method. ?

Comment: @DanielEuchar Invoke methods using reflection is slower than direct calls, but you can use FastMethod class from the "cglib" library instead of Method class. Standart java reflection use JNI-calls (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), cglib work much faster. I can find it here: http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @kornero - I believe that slow method calls is no problem here, I mean he wants to delay them...

Answer (score 1):

You could put the commands in to a data structure such as a List and pass the list to a method that executes the command and then sleeps for a period of time. A little more elegant perhaps but certainly no simpler.

You could also consider adding them to a Timer, but, again, it's more elegant but brings quite a lot of machinery without giving you much improvement in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say why you want to do this; there may be a better way to achieve your end goal than adding a bunch of delays to your code.

If this were required throughout large parts of the application, I would look at applying the delay mechanism externally:

- If this were for debugging, I would look at using the [JPDA](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/)'s [StepRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequestManager.html#createStepRequest%28com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,%20int,%20int%29) type.
- In the unlikely event you would want this in production code I would transform the target byte code using something like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Comment: I am automating few of my test cases using Java and these delays i want them to add something like thinktime.

Answer (score 0):

**Speed test:**

```
package test;

import net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastClass;
import net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastMethod;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    private static final long SLEEP = 0;
    private static final Object[] withoutParameters = new Object[0];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException, IllegalAccessException {
        final Method[] methods = getMethods(Test.class, "command1", "command2");
        final FastMethod[] fastMethods = getFastMethods(Test.class, methods);
        final Test test = new Test();
        final int loop = 10* 1000 * 1000;

        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            test.functionDirectCall();
        }
        System.out.println("DirectCall time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp));

        timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            test.functionMethod(methods);
        }
        System.out.println("Method time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp));

        timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            test.functionFastMethod(fastMethods);
        }
        System.out.println("FastMethod time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp));
    }

    private void functionDirectCall() throws InterruptedException {
        this.command1();
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
        this.command2();
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
    }

    private void functionMethod(Method... methods) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException {
        for (Method method : methods) {
            method.invoke(this);
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
        }
    }

    private void functionFastMethod(FastMethod... fastMethods) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        for (FastMethod fastMethod : fastMethods) {
            fastMethod.invoke(this, withoutParameters);
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
        }
    }

    private static Method[] getMethods(final Class aClass, final String... methodNames) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        return new ArrayList<Method>() {{
            for (String methodName : methodNames) {
                final Method method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                this.add(method);
            }
        }}.toArray(new Method[methodNames.length]);
    }

    private static FastMethod[] getFastMethods(final Class aClass, final Method... methods) {
        final FastClass fastClass = FastClass.create(aClass);
        return new ArrayList<FastMethod>() {{
            for (Method method : methods) {
                add(fastClass.getMethod(method));
            }
        }}.toArray(new FastMethod[methods.length]);
    }

    public void command1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
    }

    public void command2() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
DirectCall time:17615
Method time:19051
FastMethod time:17952
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you Help it has helped me understand this in depth.